# React.js Apollo queries and mutation error and undefined returns

Tags: reactjs, node.js, graphql, apollo

I'm having trouble configuring queries and mutations with React.js, Apollo, and GraphQL. Below I have a component with a query and mutation. These queries and mutations work with GraphiQL, but not with my React app. The query returns undefined, and the mutation gives me a status code 400 error. Within my Node.js API, I have a console.log() statement that prints the passed value to the query, so that query is receiving the request properly, and just isn't returning a value. The mutation also works with GraphiQL, but not with my React app. Below is the code that I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Component:

```
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { TEST, CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT } from "../queries/accountQueries";
import TextInputField from "./TextInputField";

function CreateAccountFormWrapper({ name, email, password, confirmPassword, onChangeState }) {
    const { testData, testLoading, testError } = useQuery(TEST, {
        variables: {
            id: 0
        }
    });
    const [ createClientAccount, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT);
    
    console.log(testData);

    return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                createClientAccount({
                    variables: {
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }
                })
            }}>
                <div className="flex col">
                <TextInputField 
                        type={"text"}
                        label={"Name"}
                        value={name}
                        onChangeState={onChangeState}
                    />
                    <TextInputField 
                        type={"text"}
                        label={"Email"}
                        value={email}
                        onChangeState={onChangeState}
                    />
                    <TextInputField 
                        type={"password"}
                        label={"Password"}
                        value={password}
                        onChangeState={onChangeState}
                    />
                    <TextInputField 
                        type={"password"}
                        label={"Confirm password"}
                        value={confirmPassword}
                        onChangeState={onChangeState}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" className="button centered"/>
                </div>
            </form>
    )
}

export default CreateAccountFormWrapper;
```

Queries:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const TEST = gql`
    query Test($id: Int!) {
        test(id: $id) {
            id
        }
    }
`;

const CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT = gql`
    mutation CreateClientAccount($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
        createClientAccount(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
            id
            auth
        }
    }
`;

export { TEST, CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT };
```

Schema:

```
const Test = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Test',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLInt }
    })
})

const AccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Account',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString }
    )}
)}

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        test: {
            type: Test,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLInt }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                console.log(args.id);
                
                return {
                    id: args.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
)}

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        createClientAccount: {
            type: AccountType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                return await account.createAccount({
                    name: args.name,
                    email: args.email, 
                    password: args.password
                });
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery,
    mutation: Mutation
})
```

Edit: The test query works but I'm getting a 400 status error when running the mutation above. I get this error:

```
Error :({ "name": "ApolloError", "graphQLErrors": [], "protocolErrors": [], "clientErrors": [], "networkError": { "name": "ServerError", "response": {}, "statusCode": 400, "result": { "errors": [ { "message": "Cannot query field \"auth\" on type \"Account\".", "locations": [ { "line": 4, "column": 5 } ] } ] } }, "message": "Response not successful: Received status code 400" }
```

And the following code is the query for creating an account:

```
createAccount: (credentials) => {
        return new Promise ((resolve) => {
            (async () => {
                var auth = generateAuthToken();
                var email = await validateEmail(credentials.email);

                if (email === "") {
                    var createAccount = `INSERT INTO accounts (name, email, password, auth) VALUES ("${credentials.name}", "${credentials.email}", "${credentials.password}", "${auth}")`;
                    
                    db.query(createAccount, async (err, res) => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        let id = await getUserID(credentials.email);
                        let accountData = {
                            id: id[0].id,
                            authToken: auth,
                            response: email
                        }   

                        return resolve(accountData);
                    });
                } else {
                    let accountData = {
                        response: email
                    }

                    return resolve(accountData);
                }
            }) ();
        })
    }
```

Edit: The issue was that there was an auth return parameter in the mutation that wasn't on the API end.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect `useQuery` Destructuring: When you use `useQuery`, the data returned is not `testData` but should be destructured as `{ data, loading, error }`. You are using `testData`, `testLoading`, `testError`, which are not the correct property names returned by `useQuery`.

so to use the data you want to use you can do `{ data:testData, loading:testLoading, error:testError }`

TIP: I suggest you read the docs once and consider error handling and tests to be written in the inital stage. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries

Comment: Thank you for your response. That solved the problem with the test query, but do you have any idea as to why the mutation is returning a 400 status error?

Comment: Can you update the error? also what does account.createAccount function return?

Comment: Is your ApolloProvider setup correctly?
Add these in your client side app and see what error is being thrown.

`if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;`
`if (error) return <p>Error :({JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</p>;`

Comment: @xxcheckmakexx I updated the question with the error and the `account.createAccount` function

Comment: Please read the error message, it is very clear.
`Cannot query field \"auth\" on type \"Account\``
 you are  requesting a field called auth that does not exist on the type `Account`